# Python not able to see environment variable in RHEL

Tags: rhel, python, environment-variables, python3

The following line of code is throwing an `environment variable was not found` error in a RHEL8 virtual machine running in Azure:

```
sourceKeys = os.environ.get("MY_ENV_VAR")
```

However, when we putty into the VM, we are able to access the variable as follows:

```
$ echo $MY_ENV_VAR
/path/to/some.yaml
```

The variable is set by packer in a startup script that has the following code:

```
export MY_ENV_VAR='/path/to/some.yaml'
echo "export MY_ENV_VAR='/path/to/some.yaml'" >> /etc/environment
echo "export MY_ENV_VAR='/path/to/some.yaml'" >> /etc/bashrc
echo "export MY_ENV_VAR='/path/to/some.yaml'" >> /etc/profile
```

Why is the linux terminal able to read the environment variable while python is not?

> **What needs to change in order for the python program to be able to read the environment variable's value?**

Comment: How is the Python program executed? Is it a systemd service, by any chance?

Answer (score 2):

`os.environ.get()`will only retrieve the value of environment variables (env-var), accessible to the process where retrieval is taking place. If your process is a daemon (as in a process launched by `systemd`) or otherwise NOT related to the execution space in which you issue `$ echo $MY_ENV_VAR` then the result may differ from what you expect.

So in a nutshell, if you are going to export a variable to make it globally available, you need to export it from the shell that also spawns the process that is used to query/retrieve the value of said env-var.

A few answers are available on stackoverflow.com and elsewhere, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27718602/4906636).